# Write a Makefile with a file without any dependency

Tags: make

I have an extremely large Makefile, which fairly simplified reads:

```
 EXEC = EXAMPLEX.exe
 FC = gfortran
 CC = gcc
 LINKER     = $(FC)
 LINK_FLAGS = 
 CPP = $(FC)
EXAMPLEX = \
  ex1.o \
  ex2.o 
OBJS = \
  $(EXAMPLEX) 
.SUFFIXES: .F .f .c .F90 .f90
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(LINKER) $(LINK_FLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@
.F.o:
    $(FC) -c $(F_FLAGS) $(CPP_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $<
.f.o:
    $(FC) -c $(F_FLAGS) $<
.F90.o:
    $(FC) -c $(F90_FLAGS) $(CPP_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $<
.f90.o:
    $(FC) -c $(F90_FLAGS) $<
.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(C_FLAGS) $<
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) *.mod

# dependencies
ex2.o:  ex1.o
```

The problem is that ex1 doesn't have any dependency ( and getting the error *** No rule to make target 'ex1.o'). My question is whether I should include `ex1.o:` among the dependencies or try something else?

Comment: The ex1.f and ex2.f files are in the subdirectory.

Comment: Your problem is that you are not using `make` but rather `gmake` and that `gmake` gives a nonsense error message in this case that confuses you. A real `make` program would give an error message similar to `make: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target 'ex1.o'` or `make: Can't find any source for 'ex1.o'.` that should be easier to understand and lead to the fact that `make` just has ben unable to find a related source file.

Comment: You're right but most current systems probably use gmake by default.